# Basic probability confusion

Tags: probability

A machine has six switches. The probability that any particular switch works properly is $0.98$. Assuming independent operation of the switches, calculate the probability that at least one switch fails to work properly.

Why isn't it this: P(not working) = $1 - 0.98 = 0.02$

There are six switches, so $1/6$ of picking on the switches. We want to find AT LEAST one. Therefore we have $6 * 1/6 * 0.02 = 0.02$

**EDIT**: I want to know **why I am wrong instead of finding the correct answer**

Comment: If your argumentation were right, the probability would be independent of the number of switches. However it is already intuitively clear that as the number of switches goes to infinity, the probability that at least one of them to not work goes to 1 (after all, on average every 50th doesn't work).

Comment: What? There are only $6$. Why infinity?

Comment: Why do you think that there are different rules for 6 switches than for any other number? How would the argumentation differ if there were 20 switches? or 50? Or a million?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I now understand how your thinking went, and therefore where it went wrong:

You are failing to take into account that after testing the first switch, you would not test it again. Also, if the first switch already failed, you don't need to test it again to see that it failed.

Also I don't see the need to test them in random order, you just test them one by one.

So you test the first switch. With a probability of $0.02$, it fails. Then you are ready (you know it failed). Otherwise (that is, with probability $0.98$) you proceed to the second switch. Again, *when you test it* it will fail with probability $0.02$ and succeed with probability $0.98$. But there's only a probability of $0.98$ that you'll even get to test it, so the probability that you find it to fail is $0.98\cdot 0.2$ and the probability that you find it to succeed is $0.98\cdot 0.98$. In the latter case, you proceed to the third switch, and so on. Unless you've found the last switch to also succeed, one of the switch failed. But the probability that the last switch succeeded is $0.98^6$ because each switch contributed a factor of $0.98$. Since the probabilities add up to $1$, this means that the probability that at least one failed is $1-0.98^6$.

Comment: Isn't there still a probablity of 1/6 of picking one that doesn't work?

Comment: @sidht: No. Where should that probability come from?

Comment: We have $1/6$ chance of picking one that may or may work?

Comment: @sidht: No. We test all six of them. If there's one that doesn't work, our chance to find it is 1. If all of the switches work, our chance to find one that doesn't work is 0. The only remaining uncertainty is whether all of them work, or not.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that at least one of the switches fails to work properly is $1 - $ the probability that none of the switches fail.  That latter probability is simply $(0.98)^6$, so the sought after probability is $1-(0.98)^6 \approx 0.114958$.

Note that the switches are independent, so the probabilities of each one failing or not multiply.

Comment: Okay but why am I wrong? That's my real question

Comment: Actually how would you go and calculate it the hard way?

Comment: @sidht The hard way is to calculate the probability that exactly $1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ or $6$ switches fail:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^6 \binom{6}{k}(0.02)^k(0.98)^{6-k}
$$

Comment: Why do we include $\binom{n}{r}$? Aren't all the switches the same?

Comment: @sidht: The $n\choose r$ tells you the number of ways that exactly $r$ of the switcvhes fail. For example, the ways exactly two switches fail are: Exactlky switches 1 and 2 fail, **or** exactly switches 1 and 3 fail, **or** … **or** exactly switch 1 and 6 fail **or** exactly switches 2 and 3 fail, **or** ... **or** exactly switches 5 and 6 fail. The number of cases is exactly $6\choose 2$, and *every single* of them has probability $0.02^2 0.98^4$; since they are mutually exclusive, their probabilities add up.